# TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated

Tags: python, streamlit

The error occurs when the following line of code is run on VSCode:

`streamlit run "filename.py"`

The error can be seen in the following image.

[image]

The localhost keeps showing "Please wait..."

What could be an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade streamlit:

```
pip install streamlit --upgrade
```

if still not

1. open powershell.exe
2. copas

   `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`
3. then run

back to IDE

- go to setting
- search "terminal windows exec" (vscode)
- if pycharm search "terminal" > tools > terminal > shell path
- change

  `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

That error happened to me with `streamlit==1.12.0`. If you have `python 3.7` pip installs `streamlit==1.12.0`

you install `python3.10` and set it default in your current terminal session

```
 alias python=/usr/bin/python3.10
```

uninstall current streamlit

```
 pip uninstall streamlit
```

install new streamlit with python 3.10

```
 python3.10 pip install streamlit
```